# RESTeasy - how to set Response field using @Context annotation

Tags: dependency-injection, resteasy

Using RESTeasy 3.0.12, the code

```
@Context
private org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse response;
```

doesn't work. Response is always null.

How to configure RESTeasy to enable the injection via @Context?

-- 
The code is pretty straightforward:
IF:

```
@Path("api/v1/admin")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public interface AdminService
{

    @PUT
    @Path("resource/{id}")
    ServiceResponse<Resource> updateResource(@PathParam("id") long ....
```

impl:

```
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService
{

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse; // <== instance always null

    @Override
    public ServiceResponse<Resource> updateResource(long resourceId, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject an instance of `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse`. From [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.12.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Context):

> The @Context annotation allows you to inject instances of javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders, javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo, javax.ws.rs.core.Request, javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.ServletConfig, javax.servlet.ServletContext, and javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext objects.

For working with the response you usually return an instance of `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` from your ResourceClass method, or you work with the `ContainerResponseContext` in a `ContainerRequestFilter` or you inject the `javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: I agree with you, but we have a given design here that prevents using javax.ws.rs.core.Response. I also tried injecting javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse but this is null either. Also tried using WEB-INF/beans.xml and adding a context paramter resteasy.scan=true - none of it is helping.

Comment: Injecting `javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse` should work. Please provide the full code of the class.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior with RESTeasy 3.0.6.Final deployed on WildFly 8.1.0.Final. Can you inject anything at all?

Comment: our app is running in jetty container without Spring.

Comment: we do not inject anything. our app is running in jetty container without Spring. we do not have CDI on the classpath. we are using javax.ws.rs.core.Context (JAX-RS) annotation, not javax.enterprise.context.spi.Context (CDI). are you using javax.enterprise.context.spi.Context to inject the HttpServletResponse instance?

Comment: Im injecting via `javax.ws.rs.core.Context`. The question was if e.g. injection of the `UriInfo` works or if you inject as parameter. I don't have a running jetty example to try. Make sure that you follow [the basic setup instructions](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.12.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e113). How are your resource classes registered?

Comment: injecting UriInfo on field level also doesn't work. injecting as a parameter does work, thou. The issue might be due to bad setup of Jetty, but then I'd expect RESTeasy not working all, rather then only a specific feature.

Comment: Make sure that you don't instantiate the resource classes yourself as Singleton in your Application class. Then the fields will of course be null.